# add Crashlytics in project have Dexguard

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, dexguard

I am tired to sync my project whit Crashlytics.
in my app using Dexguard and in release app is not synced whit Crashlytics.

and add this code in Dexguard file:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.google.firebase. { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.
-keep class com.crashlytics. { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
```

and add this code in Gradle file:

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
```

also, I comment this line in Dexguard files:

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have same issue and i was getting error in syncing:

Type 'UploadMappingFileTask' property ' doesn't have a configured value

so i added mappingFileUploadEnabled = false in gradle inside build types

```
  buildTypes {
  
    all {
      
        firebaseCrashlytics {
            mappingFileUploadEnabled = false
        }
    }

debug{
 ....
   }
 release{
......

  }
}
```